# How to properly remove error from redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a react-redux application, and I catch every error response from redux-saga, save it in the redux-store and render it in the component. The main problem is the ability to remove it when the component is updated or when the user has moved to another page. I tried to use the component lifecycle methods (componentWillUpdate), but it didn’t work correctly because I had other store parts connected to the component, and when they are updated, it clears the error before the user sees it.

My question is: is there a proper way to store/view/delete errors using the redux?

I handle errors in this way

```
export function* errorHandler(err: any): SagaIterator {
   // put an error in the redux-store
}

// it's a wrapper for every saga
export const genericErrorHandler = (saga: (...args: any[]) => SagaIterator, ...args: any[]) =>
    function* handleApp(action: any): any {
        try {
            yield call(saga, action, args);
        } catch (err) {
            yield call(errorHandler, err);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could probably give a more specific suggestion if we had more details about the design of your app & how you're handling errors. But here are some things that might help:

- split up errors by type, with separate actions/reducers/store locations for each. This will help you be specific about what kind of error has occurred and when/how to show each.
- fire an action to clear the error state. This ensures you're being specific about what errors are no longer present, and when that change occurs. If possible, don't do this as a side effect of something else happening, be specific about when & why.
- if the error state is specific to a UI component, and should be removed from the store when that component goes away, consider firing the error-clearing action in that component's `componentWillUnmount` method. This is called only when the component is being removed from the DOM.